# Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications not being received on Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to firebase. I have implemented cloud messaging in my project yet when I send the messages from the firebase console I didn't receive it .

Here is my **FirebaseInstanceIdService**

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class MyFireBaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFireBaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
// [END refresh_token]

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }}
```

and this is my **FirebaseMessagingService**

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated


    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message) {


    }
}
```

also I have included the two services into my manifest.xml

```
 <service
            android:name=".MyFireBaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: try  to write full package name in in manifest.xml  like "com.example.folderName.GCMNotificationIntentService"

Comment: That didn't solve the issue

Comment: how you are sending notification from firebase console?